# How to change the width of the left menu in Joomla (Beez20)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How can I change the width of the left menu that comes with Beez20 template in Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by editing the `/templates/beez5/css/position.css` file.

Find

```
.leftbigger
{
 width:15%
}
```

And edit the `width:15%`

Comment: Just noticed that the width of the page doesn't autofill though. So after changing the width of the left menu, you somehow have to change the width of the page as well to be as wide as the whole template(site)

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper2
{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:20px
}
```

in the same file is probably what you also need to adjust.
Using Firebug or the included development tools within a browser can tell you more here.

Comment: I tried this, however the middle column still doesn't fill all the way. If I put it to anything greater then wrapper2+left column in percentage wrapper2 will jump down (cause it can't fit). There seems to be a third column, (#right. I've changed this third column but to no avail.